# what is root cause of 'child pid 10708 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)' error?

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault, server-error, php-ini

I am getting more and more `child pid 10708 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)` errors.
what is the root cause of it and how to fix it ?

Is php ini memory is associated with this?

I am using apache2 server with php.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

It is entirely possible that your `memory_limit` variable in your `php.ini` may cause this problem. It certainly did in my case.

By lowering the `memory_limit`, I was able to resolve these errors.

Comment: I had similar issues wherever I was doing `ini_set('memory_limit', -1)` (that is, no memory limit).  Removing those instances resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is generally that the code is doing something wrong. A segmentation fault is generally what happens when a program does something that's not allowed, like trying to access memory that isn't valid.

If you're after a more specific cause, I'd be happy to list the thousand or so that spring to mind immediately :-)

On a more serious note, no. Short of knowing a great deal more, there is no easy way to give a specific answer.

The first step would be to figure out which *program* belongs to that process ID. Then you can start investigating why that program is faulting.

Answer (score 0):

Though two general answers are already posted, I want to introduce one example that I have met in these days.

If your code runs into recursive infinite loop (that causes stack overflow error), `child pid xxxxx exit signal Segmentation fault (11)` will occur.

sample code :

```
function recursiveFunc() {
    // some operation

    recursiveFunc();
}
```