# PHP not displaying errors, especially syntax

Tags: php, error-handling, xampp

I'm using PHP version 5.3.1 and CakePHP 2.3.8 with XAMPP on localhost, and only some errors are actually displayed. I can say for certain that no PHP syntax errors are displayed. 
I can't figure out what's going on, but sometimes Cake will throw out an error, and other times it won't at all, but when this happens my browser will say "No data received".

For example, if I type the following, it will go to the "No data received" screen for sure

```
echo "test"   //no semicolon
```

I've tried it on Chrome, Firefox and Safari so I'm sure it's not browser specific. I checked my error_log file and for each time this happens, the error is something like

```
child pid 90396 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

**Update - I got it working**

I was sick of hunting it down for nearly an hour so I backed up all of my projects and uninstalled XAMPP and downloaded the latest version and it's working now. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: have you changed `debug` value in core.php...set `Configure::write('debug', 2);` in `core.php`

Comment: @DipeshParmar yes, it's currently set to 2

Comment: Your problem is not cakephp related if it happens too like the example you give. You need to first check `display_errors` is properly set in `php.ini` and then verify all the other options for logging errors.

Comment: what happens if you use another browser? "no data received" is AFAIK a chrome message.

Comment: @jamie0726 It does that no matter which browser I use, as I stated in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Some people say that could be an endless loop, but when it happens, usually you see: 
**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /my/path/teste.php on line 6**

So, I think you need to check your conf files: php.ini

Have you tried to run a php file totaly apart of the cakephp with that same code (echo 'teste')? Maybe this help figure out what is happening.

Related answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745652/577470

[what is root cause of 'child pid 10708 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631228/what-is-root-cause-of-child-pid-10708-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-erro)